# pipe char in rot13-like translate command splits word at pipe

Tags: string, bash, tr

I have a rotate13 inspired script in which I want to translate an input's string to a pre-determined, but seemingly random output string. Here are the two commands I want to use to do the conversion from readable string to random output `$pWCR` and the complimentary conversion command from (seemingly) random string to original readable string `$pWCO`.

```
pWCR=$(echo $origStr|tr 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!@#$%^&*()\-_=+|\\[{]};:",./?<>' '>akHe)T[09Wo/L*}Em&YJP,\\"r;2pz_(6Usq+8u5d<RV#{iwclZtNGj?yIfn3bKFCh!X$ODQ=4\-%:]^BxM.Av@|g17S')

pWCO=$(echo $randStr|tr '>akHe)T[09Wo/L*}Em&YJP,\\"r;2pz_(6Usq+8u5d<RV#{iwclZtNGj?yIfn3bKFCh!X$ODQ=4\-%:]^BxM.Av@|g17S' 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!@#$%^&*()\-_=+|\\[{]};:",./?<>')
```

So the problem is that strings that include the pipe char `|` included in either string to be translated causes the string to to be split, actually cut-off (rather than split) at the pipe char as though it is being read as a logical OR I guess. But because it is translated inside of the single quotes I thought literal interpretation of the char should not occur. I have tried to escape the pipe char but it has no noticeable affect.

Can anyone weigh in here and let me know where my translation commands are going wrong. I could simply omit the pipe char, but I would like to know why it has to be omitted if that is the case, preferring of course to keep it in the pool of chars to translate so user is not presented unnecessarily with a list of chars that are invalid. The single quote is of course already excluded from use, but I would like to keep the list of excluded chars to that one char if possible.

**UPDATE:**
@choroba: Ok so thanks for pointing out that the command does in fact work fine on the CLI, forcing me to look more closely at the code handling the vars `$origStr` and `$randStr`.

I am using a `yad` form text box to prompt user for their input string to translate. I forgot until scrutinizing the `yad` command that it uses the pipe char '|' as the default field separator, and so was the culprit for hacking off input strings with pipe chars included.

```
userDets=$(yad --mouse --title"Restore random string to readable string" --image="$imgDPswd" " --form \
        --field="Enter random string to restore its readable value: " '' \
        --button="gtk-cancel:1" --button="gtk-ok:0") ; notSend "$LINENO" "userDets" "$userDets" "ty"

origStr=$(echo "$userDets"|sed -r 's/^([^|]*)\|.*$/\1/') ; notSend "$LINENO" "origStr" "$origStr" "ty"
```

After changing the separator to a space, like so:

```
userDets=$(yad --mouse --title"Restore random string to readable string" --image="$imgDPswd" --separator=" " --form \
        --field="Enter random string to restore its readable value: " '' \
        --button="gtk-cancel:1" --button="gtk-ok:0") ; notSend "$LINENO" "userDets" "$userDets" "ty"

    origStr=$(echo "$userDets"|sed -r 's/^([^ ]*) .*$/\1/') ; notSend "$LINENO" "origStr" "$origStr" "ty"
```

the script works as desired.

Comment: What input do you use? It works for me.

Answer (score 1):

The only problem I can see with those two statements is that the $origStr and $randStr are not enclosed in double quotes.

This will cause problems and may be causing your problem but I can't replicate your description exactly.

Comment: I went with single quotes rather than double b/c the `$` char in double quotes seems to be interpreted as variable indicator, but in single quotes interpreted simply as a dollar sign.

Comment: I mean the currently unquoted argument to the 'echo' command not the properly quoted tr command. BTW: you can put a single quote in there too by inserting the string  '"'"'  in each or the tr single quoted strings; If you can decode that. -> single-double-single-double-single.

Comment: hot-diggity! I tried for quite some time to include single quotes and couldn't get anything to work. Your advice does works so thanks for that. How come `tr` does not interpret the end of the input string at the second single quote though, and includes the single quote enclosed in double quotes and then rest of string continued with another single quote? I hope that reads somewhat comprehensible.

Comment: It's the shell that does the quote splitting. The argument consists of three quoted strings the first with single quotes the second with double quotes and the last with single quotes. The strings are concatenated together to form a single argument which is passed to tr because they don't have spaces between the strings. Single quotes have NO special characters between them so every character (except ') is interpreted literally. Double quotes have lots of special characters between them BUT the single quote is not one of them. So 'easy' (sort of ;-)